# using automatic weights- some bones dont adhere to the mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

ive made an animal model with legs. one leg makes the mesh move, the other the armature controls nothing of the mesh[image: see image] and can move freely. same problem with the frontal leg for this animal, on the same side.

i keep running into this issue and am new to blender. please advise.

thank you